# How to get predefined trips from osm

Tags: openstreetmap

I am trying to simulate the behavior of the vehicles while they are driving and I need to get some sample trips (starting-end point, similar to a route). This process should be automatic. By importing the traces. I know that planet.osm has all the information but It is too much. so the question is, is there any easy way to perform this task?
Thanks a lot for ur help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are searching for random routes? Why not just pick two random locations not too far away from each other and use one of the many [online](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/online_routers) or [offline](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/offline_routers) routers to generate a route between them? You could even add some via points to make the route more complex. Using online routers you don't even need to have a local database.

Comment: Thanks for ur help. The way I did, using drag gable points, the user chooses the initial and end point in a web map (Nokia Maps) and I get the route. :)